# why $ g(x) = x+1$ have taken?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement is true/false ?

Any continious function from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ has a fixed point.

I found the  answer but  i have  some   doubt in my mind

[image]

Comment: Because $g(x)=x$ is not just fixed-point free, it is actually the exact opposite of it.

Comment: It may be more helpful if you include a link to the original context of your question, i.e the other MSE post which you have screenshotted.

Comment: Anyway, it's really easy to find a counterexample in a direct way. Take $f:(0,1)\to (0,1), f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$. It is continuous and obviously has no fixed points.

Comment: Another solution take $f(x)=\sin x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they are saying is that there is a continuous map $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with no fixed point and that can be use to construct a a continuous map $f:(0,1) \to (0,1)$ with no fixed point. Obviously they cannot take $g(x)=x$ because they don't want $g$ to have any fixed point.